# How to prove security of scheme constructed by Hash then PRP

Tags: hash, pseudo-random-function, pseudo-random-permutation, universal-hash

Suppose there is a scheme where a message is first hashed and then sent to a PRP. If the hash is done using an $\epsilon$-bounded universal hash function and the PRP $K\times \{0,1\}^n\rightarrow\{0,1\}^n$ is a $(q,\delta)$-PRP.

The objective is to show this scheme $K\times K_n\times \{0,1\}^*\rightarrow\{0,1\}^n$
is actually a $$\biggl(q,\delta + \frac{{q\choose 2}\epsilon}{2^n}+{{q\choose 2}\epsilon}\biggr)$$ PRF.

I am able to show this scheme is a $(q,\delta+X)$-PRF, but still not finding a way how to show X to be $$\frac{{q\choose 2}\epsilon}{2^n}+{{q\choose 2}\epsilon}.$$

Comment: What have you tried so far?  How did you show that this scheme is a $(q, \delta + X)$-PRF?

Comment: Also, are you sure you meant to have a factor of $\epsilon$ in the $\binom q 2 \epsilon/2^n$ term?